# shrinkwrap won't give me nice creases

Tags: modifiers

i've got a sculpt i'm retopologizing and i'm having issues with the area where the legs connect to the body. The shrinkwrap doesn't seem to go into the creases. is there anything i can do to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it ain't fun to hear, but professional artists almost never use tools like shrinkwrap. They usually don't give a clean result, and its generally better to do the task manually. If I were you, I would just create a sphere primitive and extrude your way down the arm.

Comment: Especially since you are retopologizing, shrinkwrap isn't for you because it will give you bad vertex distribution and no intelligent placement for areas that need a higher polycount

Comment: Shrinkwrap is ok for repotology and pros do use it as a tool, not a complete solution. You can get verts to follow the surface closer by subdividing and physically placing the source vertices deeper into  crevices.